# How to map timestamp in Spring Rest?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My web service (Spring REST) receives the following POST request:

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "someKey" : "value",
 "time":"2020-01-01 11:11:11+0000"
}
```

How can I map the **time** to a variable?

I use Hibernate for ORM, but the time is saved to the database as "null" when I use Date. I tried to use Timestamp, but got a parse error.

**EDIT:**

The controller looks like this:

```
@PostMapping("/endpoint")
public MyData handlePost(@RequestBody MyData mydata){
       return repository.save(mydata);
}
```

Comment: How does the `@RequestBody` Object for your POST endpoint looks like?

Comment: Use @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "<<DateTime pattern>>") in your entity or DAO class you are using to read request body.

Comment: @DanielWosch I added how the endpoint looks like.

Comment: Could you please post the declaration of MyData? Further: what is repository in this context? Is this a JPA Repository? If so: Is myData an entity? You definitely need to provide more code and context

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ").parse(mydata.getTime());
```